# cmake Xcode framework product name not right

Tags: xcode, cmake, frameworks

I have created an Xcode framework project; everything is ok, but the product name is not right.

It should be `gpupixel.framework`, and not `gpupixel.framework/gpupixel`.

Does anyone know how to change it?

[image]

Here is my cmake file:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
        COMPILE_FLAGS "-x objective-c++"
        FRAMEWORK TRUE
        FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
        MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER net.pixpark.${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER net.pixpark.${PROJECT_NAME}
        CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR ${PROJECT_NAME}
        MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist
        # "current version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
        VERSION 1.0.1
        # "compatibility version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
        SOVERSION 1.0.1
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${EXPORT_HEADER}"
        RESOURCE "${RESOURCE_FILES}"
        #XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
    )
```

I tried many PROPERTIES, but no effect